# linux reverse engineer to find process source

Tags: linux, process, lsof

A compromised wordpress site has started several processes that run as the apache user. I can find these processes by running ps and greping for the apache user. Then I take one of the process IDs and run lsof against it to see that it has opened a bunch of tcp sockets to send mail to various recipients but I don't see the actual file that is the root of all of this. How can I drill down further to find how this is all being started? Here is an example of one of the processes:

```
~# lsof | grep 26098
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  cwd       DIR              252,0     4096          2 /
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  rtd       DIR              252,0     4096          2 /
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  txt       REG              252,0    10376     150473 /usr/bin/perl
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    22880     143572 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    35176     143571 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/Socket/Socket.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    18632     143564 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/IO/IO.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0   105720     143562 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    18600     143570 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0  2919792     137135 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    43288    1329383 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0   135366    1329380 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0  1030512    1329394 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0    14768    1329387 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0  1815224    1329389 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0  1558296     143547 /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14.2
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data  mem       REG              252,0   149280    1329381 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0       5014 /dev/null
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    1w      CHR                1,3      0t0       5014 /dev/null
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    2w      CHR                1,3      0t0       5014 /dev/null
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    3u     IPv4           51672921      0t0        TCP 172.24.14.51:51017->10.81.54.194:smtp (SYN_SENT)
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    4w     FIFO                0,8      0t0   33237048 pipe
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    5r     FIFO                0,8      0t0   33237049 pipe
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    6w     FIFO                0,8      0t0   33237073 pipe
    /sbin/ude 26098   www-data    7r     FIFO                0,8      0t0   33237074 pipe
```

Comment: can you post the result of `ps -ef | grep 26098` ?

Comment: # ps -ef | grep 26098
root      6414  2349  0 11:39 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 26098
www-data 26098     1  5 Aug15 ?        05:42:49 /sbin/udevd

Answer (score 1):

Run `pstree -p | less` to get a full list of processes running on your system, then search for `26098` and see who its parent is, then the grandparent etc.  Somewhere in that tree is your answer.

Comment: They are orphaned processes so they just fall under init. I'm sure that they are orphaned on purpose to make it hard to find the source.           init(1)-+-/sbin/udevd(26098)

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find a way to detect the source, but in my case the bot was discovered by clamav and was in /var/tmp directory.

Comment: can you edit your answer and give OP more information?